# Typical uml diagram for showing events

Tags: events, architecture, uml

I have a couple modules.  They communicate to each other through events.

What UML diagram would typically be used to show this?

Is there a non uml diagram people use?

Any examples?

Comment: What do you want express with the diagram? Do you want show the fact that the modules communicate by means of events (static structure) or do you want to show how the communicate (dynamic behaviour)?

Comment: I wanted to show that module a fires an event and it is handled by module b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you definitely want a [sequence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) to show all the event interaction between modules in sequence. This is the preferred way to represent sequence of asynchronous messages between components

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express the fact that a module A fires an event E that is handled by module B, I suggest a static diagram to show the structure of your architecture.

In particular, I would use a class diagram where I could draw:

- the modules A and B (classes with a stereotype)
- the event E (i.e. still a class with the stereotype `event`)
- an association named `subscribe` between B and E
- an association named `publish` between A and E.

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to use a "behavioral" diagram(s). There are multiple flavors. Which one you choose depends on the intent of what a given diagram wants to convey.

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/provides/behavioralmodeling.jsp