# show events and GUI classes in diagram class

Tags: events, user-interface, uml, diagram

i am currently working on a project and need to create some uml diagram properly in order to put them in my final report.

so i'm wondering if i should put the GUI classes in the diagram ? in that case, there would be a lot of informations and i fear this would make it harder to read it !
in addition to that, as i'm using observers in my program, how can i proceed to add the Event classes that i used ? i found a similar question here :
 [Typical uml diagram for showing events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923455/typical-uml-diagram-for-showing-events) 
and i dont know if it is the right way or not !

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Class Diagram` are typically used to show interaction between classes with relationship (Cardinality). It is bit like ER Diagram. For your case, If you want to show control flow between different classes with event in time ordering manner then it is better to use `Sequence Diagram` and if you want to show the relationship between different class with participation of one's object on another object then uses Class Diagram. Both diagram will certainly add some standard on your final report.

I had used `Argo UML` (free and open source software) to create those diagram. But various other tool like `Rational Rose`, `violet` or `visual Studio-2010`... are also available.